# How use bitmask operator

Tags: c#, bitmask

I'm learning bit mask. And found and example but couldn't make it work.

I'm trying to calculate all sum combination from one array.
The result should be

> 0 - 1 - 2 - 3 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6

My problem is with (i & mask) should only result in {0,1} and isn't.
Instead is producing.

> 0 - 1 - 4 - 5 - 12 - 13 - 16 - 17

```
        int[] elem = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

        double maxElem = Math.Pow(2, elem.Length);

        for (int i = 0; i < maxElem; first++)
        {
            int mask = 1, sum = 0;
            for (int run = 0; run < elem.Length; run++)
            {
                sum += elem[run] * (i & mask);
                mask <<= 1;
            }
            Debug.Write(sum + " - ");
        }
```

Comment: `i & mask` will produce either 0 or `mask`, not 0 or 1: Eg. `0110b & 0100b == 0100b`, and  `1010b & 0100b == 0000b`

Comment: In your case `mask` is 2^`run` so that means only one bit is set - not that it's 1 or 0

Comment: @Blorgbeard I want sum {0,1}elem[0] + {0,1}elem[1] + {0,1}elem[2] for all combination. The {0,1} changes I think can be solve by a bitmask sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solve it creating an IF.

```
int[] elem = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
double maxElem = Math.Pow(2, elem.Length);

for (int i = 0; i < maxElem; first++)
{
    for (int run = 0; run < elem.Length; run++)
    {
        int mask = 1, sum = 0;
        if ((i & mask) > 0) // ADD THIS LINE
        {
            sum += elem[run];                    
        }
        mask <<= 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> `(i & mask)` should only result in {0,1} and isn't

`(i & mask)` should return a result in {0,1} only when `mask` is `1` - that is, on the initial iteration. However, as soon as `mask` gets shifted by `mask <<= 1` operation, the result of the next operation will be in {0,2}. As the mask gets shifted, possible results will become {0,4}, {0,8}, {0,16} and so on, because the only bit set to `1` in the mask would be moving to the left.

The reason why `<<` operator doubles the number is the same as the reason why writing a zero after a decimal number has the effect of multiplying the number by ten: appending a zero to a number of any base is the same as multiplying that number by the value of base.